# Image is not displaying in new Activity while putting onclickListener in RecyclerViewAdapter using VOLLEY

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-volley

Image is not  displaying in new activity...I am putting OnclickListener on RecyclerViewAdaptor... I am using Volley... I want to display both image and text in new activity..but only text is displaying!!..Can anyone help me?

I think the problem is in the intent part....but I am not able to get why the image is not displaying

MyAdaptor.java

```
package com.example.volleydemo;


import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.service.autofill.UserData;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

public class MyAdaptor extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdaptor.myviewholder>
{
    DisplayUser data[];

    Context context;

    public MyAdaptor(DisplayUser[] data, Context context) {
        this.data = data;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public myviewholder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        //create layout like custom_link.xml
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.custom_list_item,parent,false);
        return new myviewholder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull myviewholder holder, int position)
    {

        holder.t1.setText(data[position].getName());
        holder.t2.setText(data[position].getDesig());
        Glide.with(holder.t1.getContext()).load("http://10.0.2.2/volley/images/"+data[position].getImage()).into(holder.img);

        holder.img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                //Toast.makeText(context,"image : "+holder.img,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

               Intent intent = new Intent(context,DetailsActivity.class);
               intent.putExtra("imagename",data[position].getImage());
               intent.putExtra("header",data[position].getName());
               intent.putExtra("desc",data[position].getDesig());
               intent.putExtra("rollno",data[position].getRollno());

               intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
               context.startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.length;
    }

    class myviewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
  {
      ImageView img;
      TextView t1,t2;

      public myviewholder(@NonNull View itemView) {
          super(itemView);

          img = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img);
          t1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.t1);
          t2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.t2);

      }
  }
}
```

this is new acticity file
DetailsActivity.java

```
package com.example.volleydemo;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

public class DetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView img;
    TextView tv1,tv2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_details);

        img = findViewById(R.id.desc_img);
        tv1 = findViewById(R.id.desc_header);
        tv2 = findViewById(R.id.desc_desc);

        img.setImageResource(getIntent().getIntExtra("imagename",0));
        //Glide.with(holder.t1.getContext()).load("http://10.0.2.2/volley/images/"+data[position].getImage()).into(holder.img);

        tv1.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("header"));
        tv2.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("desc"));
    }
}
```

This is the holder class..
DisplayUser.java

```
package com.example.volleydemo;

public class DisplayUser {
    //this is helper class

    private String rollno,name,desig,image;

    public DisplayUser() {

    }

    public DisplayUser(String rollno, String name, String desig, String image) {
        this.rollno = rollno;
        this.name = name;
        this.desig = desig;
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getRollno() {
        return rollno;
    }

    public void setRollno(String rollno) {
        this.rollno = rollno;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDesig() {
        return desig;
    }

    public void setDesig(String desig) {
        this.desig = desig;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your **DetailsActivity**,

**Replace:**

```
  img.setImageResource(getIntent().getIntExtra("imagename",0));
  Glide.with(holder.t1.getContext()).load("http://10.0.2.2/volley/images/"+data[position].getImage()).into(holder.img);
```

**To:**

```
 Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load("http://10.0.2.2/volley/images/"+getIntent().getStringExtra("imagename").into(img);
```